# Sharepoint - Pitfalls to plan around?

Tags: sharepoint, documentation

Management is taking steps to rectify an issue with have with document management. The issue with our document manage is: we don't have any...

Currently, we have a drive on the NAS with upwards of 90,000 documents, in various levels of organisation.

A decision has been made to implement Sharepoint as an instrument to help control/track our documentation. We are doing it in stages, with the next stage being to migrate one of my team's documentation into Sharepoint. The documentation consists mainly of troubleshooting documents and incident reviews.

**What common pitfalls of using Sharepoint should we look out for in terms of maintaining order on the documentation?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't try to replicate the file system in SharePoint. Define and make use of useful metadata to aid searching and finding information.
2. Make sure you turn on versioning for document libraries (one of the benefits is that this lets end-users retrieve/rollback accidentally overwritten documents instead of asking IT to restore from backups)
3. Force check-outs if you can. This prevents multiple people from editing the same file.
4. Permissions are a pain, but you can generally set them to do what you want. Try to inherit permissions wherever possible and use SharePoint groups and AD groups instead of assigning permissions to individuals.

Comment: All above are right on the money. Make sure you ahve someone who REALLY understands SharePoint working on the project.

Comment: @ DaveM. Unfortunately, we don't and that decision is out of my hands. I'm doing my best to get across it as much as possible.